# Add Property to ControlsFX PropertySheet

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I am creating a `PropertySheet` and I want to add a `Property` to the sheet. The problem is, what happens if the value of the property changes, the `PropertySheet` needs to update to reflect those changes. How would I do this?

```
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.beans.property.Property;

import org.controlsfx.control.PropertySheet;

public class PropertyItem implements PropertySheet.Item {
    private Map<String, Property> map;
    private String key;
    private String name;
    private String description;

    PropertyItem(Map<String, Property> map, String key, String name, String description){
        this.map = map;
        this.key = key;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public String getCategory() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getType() {
        return map.get(key).getValue().getClass();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return map.get(key).getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object arg0) {
        map.get(key).setValue(arg0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too late but anyway...

The property editor uses the following method from PropetySheet.Item interface to listen to value changes.

`optional<ObservableValue<? extends Object>> getObservableValue();`

You need to implement this method on your PropertyItem class.